# JavaX naming.NameNotFoundException with Jboss/Wildfly, what is the name about?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, wildfly

Will keep this short.
We have been tasked with following this tutorial in my class:
https://webdev.jhuep.com/~jcs/ejava-javaee/coursedocs/content/html_single/ejb-basic-lab-book.html#ejb-basicex-modules-server-setup

The tutorial is very fast at times, and confusing. My issue is that I've come to 2.3, and I have just made my testmodule, and I am at the point where my server is up and I am doing a MVN clean install.

I get this error message:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.82 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.myorg.basicejb.earejb.ReservationIT
[ERROR] testPing(org.myorg.basicejb.earejb.ReservationIT)  Time elapsed: 0.703 s  <<< ERROR!
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jms -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.jms
```

I have checked everywhere and I'm not entirely sure what this is about. Is this my application not finding the name of the server? Because if I shut the server down, then it can't find and connect so I'm not sure it's the name either.

I understand my question might be vague, but what exactly am I missing? Is the tutorial assuming I should know more about JBoss/Wildfly or? (As in, is there something I should do inside JBoss somehow?)

Again, I'm very new at all this, and I'm very thankful for any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start Wildfly with the `./bin/standalone.sh` command it uses `standalone.xml` from the $WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/configuration directory.  From [this link](https://docs.wildfly.org/17/Getting_Started_Guide.html#wildfly-10-configurations) you want the "full" version if you want to use JMS:

> Standalone Server Configurations
>
> **standalone.xml (default)**
>
> Java Enterprise Edition 8 web profile
>   certified configuration with the required technologies plus those
>   noted in the table above.
>
> **standalone-ha.xml**
>
> Java Enterprise Edition 8 web profile certified
>   configuration with high availability
>
> **standalone-full.xml**
>
> Java Enterprise Edition 8 full profile certified
>   configuration including all the required EE 8 technologies
>
> **standalone-full-ha.xml**
>
> Java Enterprise Edition 8 full profile
>   certified configuration with high availability

To run with the full version change your command line to be:

```
./bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml
```

Comment: I get a new error now "Error running 'JBOSS'
Cannot runt program "C:/.......": createprocess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32-program"?

It seems as if it's not meant to do it that way or am I doing something else wrong now?

Comment: @harrigaturu - can you edit your question or create a new one with the full error?

Comment: The issue was that I was on Windows, didn't know .sh scripts are for Linux.